# Function always returns meaningless value

Tags: c, python-3.x, pypy, python-cffi

I'm writing C functions to be called in pypy3 by cffi. However, the wrapped functions always return a meaningless value in pypy3, no matter what the true return value is.

The output of the `printf()` function tells me everything works fine in the C function, but the return value in pypy3 is changed.

The C function is written like this:

```
double test(){
    return 5.12;
}

double test2(){
    double tmp=test();
    printf("!!!!!!!%f\n",tmp);
    return tmp;
}
```

The cffi build script is as follows:

```
from cffi import FFI
ffibuilder = FFI()

ffibuilder.set_source("_faststr_cffi",
                      """
                        #include <Python.h>
                        #include "stdint.h"
                        #include <string.h>
                        typedef uint32_t char32_t;
                      """,
                      sources=['faststr_purec.c']
                      )   # library name, for the linker

ffibuilder.cdef("""
double test();
double test2();
""")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ffibuilder.compile(verbose=True)
```

I tried to call test2() in pypy3 console:

```
>>>> from _faststr_cffi import lib
>>>> lib.test2()
!!!!!!!5.120000
16.0
```

The printf tells me that return value should be 5.120000, but it returned 16.0 in pypy3.

I found some clue: If I change the string in test2() printf function, the return value of test2 in pypy3 is changed.

Update: Result in cpython 3.6.7 is the same so it's not a pypy3 problem

Comment: Weird question, but is it always the number of characters written? Because that's what it looks like here

Comment: @EdwardMinnix Indeed, this is a good catch, which lead to the identification of the reason of the misbehaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is as follows:

Here, you declare the functions `test()` and `test2()`:

```
ffibuilder.cdef("""
double test();
double test2();
""")
```

These declarations are only for the cffi interface to know the return values to use. But the declarations for the native c functions `test()` and `test2()` are missing. Thus, they are implicitly declared returning `int`!

Now when the function `test()` is called (which is implicitly declared returning int) from test2

```
double tmp = test();

return tmp;
```

the compiled code reads *the wrong register* (because it looks for an integer value) and converts it to a double, returning it as a result. As it happens, the last integer result was the result of the `printf()`, which is the length of the printed string. Because of this, you get the result of `16` in your case.

The fix is, to declare the functions `test()` and `test2()` properly:

```
ffibuilder.set_source("_faststr_cffi",
                  """
                    #include <Python.h>
                    #include "stdint.h"
                    #include <string.h>
                    typedef uint32_t char32_t;
                    double test();
                    double test2();
                  """,
                  sources=['faststr_purec.c']
                  )   # library name, for the linker
```

Then it should work as expected.

Comment: I think you are right. But could you please explain more about why printf print the correct return value 5.120000?

Comment: @Jay It's a matter of calling conventions. `test()` returns a double in register A, but `test2()` looks for an integer in register B, since `test()` is (implicitly) declared returning an integer. The integer stored in register B is the return value of `printf()`, which is not overwritten before returning from `test()`.